# Is it possible to send a Int[] to an Oracle Stored Procedure using OleDb

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g, oledb

Is it possible to send an `int[]` from a c# application using OleDb to an Oracle Stored Procedure?

I was wondering if there is a specific way of setting up both c# `OleDbType` and the type in the Oracle stored procedure. At the moment I am using this kind of setup.

C#

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 1, 2};

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("var_name", intArray));
cmd.Parameters[i].OleDbType = OleDbType.Variant
cmd.Parameters[i].Size = 20;
```

Oracle

```
TYPE intArray IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
PROCEDURE proc(var_name IN intArray);
```

Thankyou in advance - Ankou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix my own problem.

Seeing as no one has came up with a solution I decided to fix this problem by sending in a string of CSV, then created a split method in order to add each value to `TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;` which could then be used elsewhere.

So have a solution and a String Split function too :)